# What is the correct order to multiply vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw the equation: $$|A\rangle =\sum_i\alpha_i|i\rangle$$
Which could be also written like that:$$|A\rangle=\sum_i|i\rangle\langle i|A\rangle$$
I know that $\langle i|A\rangle=\alpha_i$, but can I take the product of $|i\rangle\langle i|$then multiply the result with $|A\rangle$?
And if so, is this $|i\rangle\langle i|$ called the outer product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, $|i\rangle\langle i|$ is defined as the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). The outer product of two $n \times 1$ vectors produces an $n \times n$ matrix. So from the equation you provided, by taking the outer product you would find a matrix (the identity matrix) acting on $A$. So in short, yes you can do this.

We can also see that, as you mentioned, $\langle i|A\rangle=\alpha_i$. Recall that $\alpha_i$ is just a number, and numbers commute (order of multiplication doesn't matter).

To illustrate with a simple example:

\begin{align}
|A\rangle &= \sum_{i=0}^1 |i\rangle\langle i|A\rangle \\
&= |0\rangle\langle 0|A\rangle + |1\rangle\langle 1|A\rangle \\
&= \left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    +
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
  \right) |A\rangle \\
&= I|A\rangle \\
&= |A\rangle
\end{align}